# Feed Me in Templates - can't pull in <itunes:summary>

Tags: templating, plugin-feedme

I'm using Feedme to [display content in my temmplates](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/feature-tour/using-in-your-templates) from a podcast RSS feed - **not** importing entries, just displaying.

Everything is working fine except that I can't display the `<itunes:summary>` node.

When I use this code

```
{# podcaast #}
{% set params = {
    url: 'https://website101podcast.com/feed.rss',
    type: 'rss',
    element: 'item',
    cache: 60,
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}


{% for node in feed|reverse %}
  {% if loop.index <= 1 %}
    <h3 >{{ node.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ itunes:summary }}</p>
    <a href="{{ node.link }}">Listen Now</a><!-- /.btn btn-default -->
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following template errors:

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected).

Is it possible to call in the itunes field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll not be able to use the dot notation here, and instead use the array notation.

Try: `{{ node['itunes:summary'] }}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's this line: `<p>{{ itunes:summary }}</p>`. Does `<p>{{ itunes.summary }}</p>` work (replaced the : with a .)?

Comment: Nope, I tried that before posting